# Retrieving data from mySQL and displaying in HTML table as buttons

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql

I want to get data from mysql and display in a table in my HTML file as a button and then link the button to some URL.
I have got the data up as buttons but having trouble linking them. Bear in mind I am a fairly new user of html/javascript/php!

This code correct displays all the items as buttons in a table:

```
<?php
$connection = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "password");
mysql_select_db("maindatabase", $connection); 
$query_search = "select * from login where _id = '5' ";       
$query_exec = mysql_query($query_search) or die(json_encode("0")); 


while($line = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_exec)) {
echo '<tr>'; 
$temp = $line['user'];
echo '<td><button type="button" onclick="toggleFollowing('.$line['user'].')">'.         ($temp).'</button></td>';

echo '</tr>';
}

?>
```

This is the javascript for linking the buttons to a website:

```
<script 
       type="text/javascript">
function toggleFollowing(name_id) {
window.location = 'www.google.com';
}
</script>
```

Whenever I click the button I get the error: 
Uncaught RefreceError: 'nameofbutton' is not defined

Any ideas?

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to escape the quotes since you are passing string as a parameter in toggleFollowing function.  You have to escape with backslash. Please try this:

```
<?php
$connection = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "password");
mysql_select_db("maindatabase", $connection); 
$query_search = "select * from login where _id = '5' ";       
$query_exec = mysql_query($query_search) or die(json_encode("0")); 


while($line = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_exec)) {
echo '<tr>'; 
$temp = $line['user'];
echo '<td><button type="button" onclick="toggleFollowing(/'.$line['user'].'/)">'.         ($temp).'</button></td>';

echo '</tr>';
}


?>
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks this worked!! Just need a quick temporary solution, will look into mySqli or PDO in the future :)

Answer (score 0):

nameofbutton can not be found anywhere in your code

so my best guess is that it's taken from the database

maybe $line['user'] actually contains single quote (') that mess up your code, try to see source code from your browser